# How to access the __setitem__ definition | Syntax & Examples?

Tags: python, oop, matrix

I have a matrix class similar to [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578131-a-simple-matrix-class/):

```
class Matrix(object):

    def __init__(self, m, n, init=True):
        if init:
            self.rows = [[0]*n for x in range(m)]
        else:
            self.rows = []
        self.m = m
        self.n = n

    def __setitem__(self, idx, item):
        self.rows[idx] = item
        print("HERE")

    ...
```

I would like to set an element to a value of 2:

```
my_mat = 0000                    my_mat = 0000
         0000           ->                0200
         0000                             0000
         0000                             0000
```

and in my `main()` I set the element like this:

```
from matrix import Matrix

def main():

    # Create matrix
    my_mat = Matrix(4,3)

    # Set element
    my_mat[1][1] = 2
    print(my_mat)


if __name__ == "__main__":

    main()
```

The `__setitem__` definition requires 3 args, (one which is `self`, that is provided automatically). So, `id` and `item` are needed. I have tried a number of different combinations to set an element of the matrix. When I try to set the element (above), "HERE" isn't printed. It appears that I'm not accessing the `__setitem__` method at all.

How do I set an element using the `__setitem__` def? Syntax and examples would be appreciated.

I have tried variations like:

```
my_mat(1,1) = 2
my_mat(1,1,2)
my_mat([1,1],2)
```

.... but all fail.

Comment: You're making a lot of references to the same list in your constructor, and you're going to be surprised later.

Comment: To elaborate you should do `self.rows = [[0 for _ in range(n)] for x in range(m)]`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Writing a Custom Matrix Class in Python, \_\_setitem\_\_ issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16248012/writing-a-custom-matrix-class-in-python-setitem-issues)

Comment: Just to clarify - my Matrix class includes all the definitions such as the `__getitem__` , `__str__` and `__repr__`  etc. as outlined in [here](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/578131-a-simple-matrix-class/). I have just omitted them from the question for brevity by using the `...`

Comment: The recipe you're using doesn't provide access to the individual elements of the matrix the way you'd like. Look at everything in the recipe's `MatrixTests` as well as the all the examples shown in the "Sample usage": section. The class' own code only accesses entire rows at once, i.e. `ret[x] = row`, which do go through the class' `__setitem__` method. Another way to say this is that the `item` argument passed to `__setitem__()` is an entire row. Also note that the `idx` argument is a row index and each row is simply as list, which have their own `__setitem__` method.

Comment: @JamesPeterMcConnell  `my_mat[1][1] = 2` does not call `my_mat.__setitem__` but `my_mat[1].__setitem__`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `__setitem__()` method in the `Matrix` class in the linked ActiveState recipe is for accessing entire rows (likewise for the `__getitem__()` method).

So, to invoke its  `__setitem__()` method would require something like the following, which first retrieves the entire row, changes a single element of it, and then stores the entire row back into the matrix at the same row index:

```
def main():

    # Create matrix
    my_mat = Matrix(4,3)

    # Set single element, logically equivalent to my_mat[1][1] = 2
    row = my_mat[1]  # Uses Matrix.__getitem__()
    row[1] = 2       # Change single element of row.
    my_mat[1] = row  # Uses Matrix.__setitem__() to replace row
    print(my_mat)
```

As written, the recipe does *not* provide a way to do this all with a single line of code. If it's going to be done frequently, you're will need to modify the definition of the the `Matrix` class itself.

If you can't figure out how to do that, find a different recipe that supports it (or ask another question here. I suppose).

Parting thought: I suggest you look into getting and installing the [`numpy`](https://pypi.org/project/numpy/) add-on module (it's not built-in to Python). It also has a number of other useful features and is very fast.

*Minor Update*

For fun, I figured-out a very hacky and unreadable way to do it in a single line of code:

```
    # Logically equivalent to my_mat[1][1] = 2
    my_mat[1] = (lambda r, i, v: (r.__setitem__(i, v), r)[1])(my_mat[1], 1, 2)
```

This defines an inline anonymous function that accepts 3 arguments, `r`, `i`, and `v`:

1. `r`: row to modify
2. `i`: index of item within the row
3. `v`: new value for item

This function calls row `r`'s `__setitem__()` method (each row being a sublist in the recipe) to modify the item's value within the row, and then returns the modified row, which is assigned back to same row position it was retrieved from (overwriting its original value).

The `Matrix` class' `__setitem__()` will get called to perform the final step of replacing the entire row.

(I'm not recommending you do it this way...but hopefully this will give you the an idea about what a new method to the class would have o o since that would need to do something similar.)

Comment: Thanks for the input. My snippet above produces the output you have expressed. However, "HERE" is not printed to the console as expected if the __setitem__ def was called. my_mat[1][1] = 2 is like manually setting the matrix. My question relates to setting a matrix element using the __setitem__ def. Any thoughts?

Comment: James: `__setitem__()` isn't being called because the `__getitem__()` method returns a `list` object, not a `Matrix` instance. This is because The `rows` attribute of  `Matrix` instances is a list (of sublists). Whenever the `Matrix` class' `__getitem__()` is called, it returns one of the sublists in `self.rows`. The built-in `list` has its own `__setitem__()` which unaffected (i.e. has nothing to do) with the one in your `Matrix` class. In my opinion this a bug in the linked ActiveState recipe.

Comment: James: P.S. One way to fix this would be to define your own `Row` class that has it's own `__setitem__()` and `__getitem__()` methids and have the `Matrix` class create a list of them instead of a list-of-lists. In other words a list-of-Rows.

Answer (score 0):

I think in this situation you would want to define `__getitem__` and have it return the proper row:

```
def __getitem__(self, item):
    if isinstance(item, int):
        return self.rows[item]
    return super().__getitem__(item)
```

Or, alternatively, define a more complex `__setitem__` as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16248029/6806787)

Also, unrelated to your question, note that the `else` branch in your constructor will initialize `rows` as a one-dimensional list instead of two-dimensional, not sure if you meant to do that.